# Yii1 - the config file is not loading

Tags: yii, config, yii1.x

The main reason for not loading a config file in the server which worked well in localhost:

**Code Snippet from public_html/admin.php**

```
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '../framework/yii.php';
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/admin/config/main.php';

print_r($config);
```

**Result in localhost:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\*****/admin/config/main.php
```

**Result in sever:**

```
/home/folder_name/domains/*****/public_html/admin/config/main.php
```

**Sever Result from public_html/index.php:**

```
/home/folder_name/domains/******/public_html/protected/config/main.php
```

I am writing this because I had spent hours to trace the point.Its working in FrontEnd but not working in BackEnd. What was the main reason?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer:

```
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '../framework/yii.php';
```

This code is used during multiple domain on single hosting. But the code needs correction:

```
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/yii.php';
```

> I have uploaded framework folder within public_html.